# Not seeing new start page for Safari on Catalina

Tags: safari, catalina

Downloaded the new update to Catalina that was supposed to come with a new look to the Safari start page.  I see things exactly the same as they were before.  Am I supposed to do something to enable this feature?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions here.  What "new update to Catalina" are you referring to?  Remember, not everyone is reading this question immediately after you post it.

Comment: Referring to the major update released this week.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the feature you're looking for?  Your question is missing a lot of info right now so you might not get quality answers or answers that actually help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what you are seeing or expecting to see, but from what I see in Safari 13 on macOS Mojave, the favicon styles of Favorited websites look different. They are rounder and have a more transparent background. From a picture I saw about Safari in Catalina, it looks like it also has Siri suggestions below the favorites section. It didn’t look like there where any extreme differences.